# How to use attribution in Firebase?

Tags: firebase, networking, firebase-analytics, attribution

i am planning to work with network partners that are available in Firebase attribution, there are plenty of them.
I am using Unity and succesfully integrated Firebase in project.
I wonder do i need to integrate every sdk of this network list to be able to work with them? I was under the impression that Firebase handles it automatically, i mean i thought all i need to do is register at the network's site and paste the generated link from firebase to track my campaigns, am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to implement any of the Ad Network SDK and only Firebase, this is the beauty of Firebase.

You need to implement Firebase SDK in your app and use the Campaign URL generated in your Firebase Console and insert it in the AdNetworks tracking URL box.

To get the URL, go to Firebase Console --> Project --> App --> Analytics --> Attribution --> Network Settings --> New Network --> Select network of your choice --> Get the campaign URL in the campaign URL box.

In the conversion events table, you should be able to see the download via any of the Firebase Supported Ad Networks that you have run a campaign with under first_open event.